# Excel VBA - copy and paste column then clear constants

Tags: excel, vba

I am copying and pasting a range to the first empty column with the code below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim lastCol As Long
lastCol = Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Sheets("My Sheet").Range("D4:D119").Copy
With Cells(4, lastCol + 1)
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
End With
End Sub
```

The desired outcome is to then delete the constants from the copied range, however the code above deletes all constants in the worksheet. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If only one cell is the source to this, the whole sheet is used. Simply change the line to:

```
.EntireColumn.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
```

or (if you also want to exclude row 1 to 3 in that column):

```
Range(Cells(4, lastCol + 1),Cells(Rows.Count, lastCol + 1)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, 
Range(Cells(4, lastCol + 1),Cells(Rows.Count, lastCol + 1)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents did the trick.

Comment: One more question on this - the code only copies the range and pastes it to the first empty column once, when i click the command button again, it appears to just copy and paste into the same column, not the next empty column as intended. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Did you run the `lastCol = ...` line again? And is the cell in row 4 used?